# Union with two queries returns "Call to undefined method stdClass::union()" error

Tags: database, laravel, union

I'm currently trying to union two queries but unfortunately they return an error.

```
$bitfinex = DB::table('bitfinex')->select('price')->latest()->first();
$bitstamp = DB::table('bitstamp')->select('price')->latest()->first()->union($bitfinex);
```

Returns this error:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method stdClass::union()
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first() is fetching the first result from your query.  At that point, the query is already submitted to the database server and can't be unioned.

If you want only one result from each select, use the limit() method, which corresponds to SQL limit.

```
$bitfinex = DB::table('bitfinex')->select('price')->latest()->limit(1);
$bitstamp = DB::table('bitstamp')->select('price')->latest()->limit(1);

$results = $bitfinex->union($bitstamp)->get();
```

get() will fetch a collection of the results, as opposed to first() which will only fetch the first result (row).

Comment: I think it will just give 1 result , OP might be  looking for 1st records of each queries

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, updating my answer now.